# Disabling digit grouping in a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, number-formatting, jspinner

I needed a widget to select a TCP/UDP port, so I wrote the following:

```
public static JSpinner makePortSpinner()
{
    final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(
            new SpinnerNumberModel( DefaultPort, 1024, 65535, 1 ) );
    spinner.setFont( Monospaced );
    return spinner;
}
```

...`Monospaced` and `DefaultPort` being static constants.

I would like to remove the digit grouping characters from the resulting display.  For example, the default of 55024 displays as "55,024", where I would like it to be "55024".  I know that straight `NumberFormat`, as I might use with `JFormattedTextField`, has a `setGroupingUsed(boolean)` method for this purpose.  Is there anything like this for `JSpinner`?  Should I subclass `SpinnerNumberModel`?

Comment: ((-: That, with port numbers was exactly my problem too!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the format of the number editor on your spinner:

```
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner,"#"));
```

or to be more explicit:

```
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner);
editor.getFormat().setGroupingUsed(false);
spinner.setEditor(editor);
```

Comment: The second one _almost_ works:  it is initially sized and drawn with grouping, but that goes away if I edit it or force it to redraw.  The first seems to work fine, though; thank you very much!